# CakePHP beforeFind conditions

Tags: php, cakephp, activerecord, cakephp-model

I am looking for something very intuitive.

There are several models with data and each record has a `status` field. So if admin I need to see all the records both with status '1' and '0' but for the frontend I need to set some global `beforeFind` which will find only the data with `status`=1

Also some of the models `hasMany` and others `belongsTo` so this data should also be filtered  for the frontend to show only the data with `status`=1

Comment: Some code will help us ... What query you using to display record in front ? Have you tried giving the condition ?

Comment: Some of the controllers use simple `find`, others `paginate` , so need something for all. Of course if I set the condition in the `find` or `paginate` I will get the needed result but still if the Model `hasMany` I will get those even if status=0

Answer (score 1):

You could do this easily by adding a rule in the model's `beforeFind` callback which adds `'status' => 1` to the conditions, *unless `'status'` is already set*. So you can override the condition at any time, but it'll default to `1`.

You should make such things explicit though, instead of relying on magic callback behavior. The best way would be to create a method in the model like `findPublicItems`, which adds the condition to the condition array. In all your controller methods where you only want to show `status = 1` items, explicitly call this method. In the admin interface, do whatever you want using the regular find methods.

Comment: and is there a way the model to check if admin?

Comment: Technically the answer is *yes*, but this is really the wrong way to go about it. The model should not care. It's not the model's job to care. The model just gets data, deciding what data to get is the controller's job. Therefore, you can *prepare* certain methods in the model that make it easy to get the right data, but don't let the model decide which data it returns.

Comment: Works ok for the current model data but this does not filter the `hasMany`. Also how to set the`conditions` => `status` globally in the controller (ex. in the befereFilter ?) where I can check if admin